# NodeJS - Async and Mongoose promise callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I am new to Javascript promises, async functions, etc.

I have problem with async library and Mongoose data fetch:

```
async.eachOfSeries(items, function (item, callback) {
    Set.find({appid: item.appid}).exec()
        .then((item2) => {
            //Do something with item2
            callback();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            callback();
        });
}, function () {
    console.log("Success");
});
```

`callback()` cannot be called inside Mongoose promise.
`TypeError: callback is not a function`

How to make this system work please?

Comment: Why cant it? ...

Comment: TypeError: callback is not a function

Comment: Cause its signature is `item, key, callback` ...

Comment: Sure! Thanks man! I am idiot :D

Comment: why would you use a callback inside of a promise? they're opposite ways of handling async calls. instead of passing in a callback, why not just call the function in the .then()?